# Get the current username

Tags: c#, list, sql-server-2008

I want to insert the current logonname into a SQL Server 2008 database. The logon name is already in the `Euser` class as shown here

[image]

And I want to use that logon name in my insert script as shown

[image]

How will I do that?

Comment: Let me know if you are looking for more details from my end.

Comment: Please put code directly into your question, not images. The images are difficult to read, cannot be copied into example code, and may disappear leaving a meaningless question behind.

Comment: @HABO i will keep in mind next time thank you

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Use [`CURRENT_USER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176050.aspx) or [`USER_NAME()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188014.aspx)</strike>

**UPDATE**: Use [SYSTEM_USER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179930.aspx)

> You can use the SYSTEM_USER function with DEFAULT constraints in the
>   CREATE TABLE and ALTER TABLE statements. You can also use it as any
>   standard function. If the user name and login name are different,
>   SYSTEM_USER returns the login name. If the current user is logged in
>   to SQL Server by using Windows Authentication, SYSTEM_USER returns the
>   Windows login identification name in the form: DOMAIN\user_login_name.
>   However, if the current user is logged in to SQL Server by using SQL
>   Server Authentication, SYSTEM_USER returns the SQL Server login
>   identification name, such as WillisJo for a user logged in as
>   WillisJo. SYSTEM_USER returns the name of the currently executing
>   context. If the EXECUTE AS statement has been used to switch context,
>   SYSTEM_USER returns the name of the impersonated context.

So, this would be your update statement:

```
UPDATE dbo.mfworkorder with (rowlock) SET jobstarted=1, lasteditdt=GETDATE(), lastedited=SYSTEM_USER WHERE workorderno=@WorkOrderNo
```

Comment: It inserting in database as "dbo" not the  logon user.. Please advice !!@jalal

Comment: system_user giving my database username. it not giving me username which i put to get-in in application . Please advice

Comment: @sony921 Update your question and put your INSERT statement, Table structure and Ensure class here and describe in what scenario you want to insert this data to database. Please do not put any image. In this way people can help you better.